# Home folders accessible to other users and should not be, how to fix?

Tags: permissions, security, home-directory

Why are my home folders accessible by other users on the same system by default?  I understand that I can change the permission of the home folders but want to know why this happened?

I have done nothing to make the folders "shareable" and yet I can easily navigate to any users home folder using Nemo 2.4.5 and see all their contents.

This is quite a privacy and security flaw and I'm not sure why it has defaulted this way on my system.

Under Users and Groups (items checked =) (both are administrator accounts)

User 1 = adm, cdrom, dip, lpadmin, plugdev, sudo

User 2 = User 2, sudo

Also of note is why User 2 has User 2 clicked but User 1 does not have User 1 clicked.  Both accounts appear to behave exactly the same.

Thank you for any tips in this matter.

Answer (score 5):

The default umask is `022`, which allows group and others read permissions (and execute, where applicable) (or `002` if [User Private Groups are enabled](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=581413)). If you have a problem with that being the default, file a bug. If you want to change the default, edit `/etc/login.defs` and change

```
UMASK       022
```

to

```
UMASK       077
```

And then do:

```
chmod og-rx -R ~
```

Comment: I learned something today!  Thanks (and upvoted)!

Answer (score 2):

If using the graphical interface or the `adduser` command to create the users, you can modify this in the file `/etc/adduser.conf` as explained in the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/adduser.conf.5.html), by changing *DIR_MODE* from 0755 to 0700 or whatever you want.

Also, for `useradd`, see [this answer in SuperUser's forum.](https://superuser.com/a/304000/416849)

Comment: in terminal    sudo chmod 700 /home/user (user is your account name)      seems to be a simple and fast fix!  thx guys!